# Adequate choice of T-Test

Tags: t-test, medicine

I have a question regarding comparability of t-test variants.

The experimental set-up is the following: 
Comparison of Gene Expression Level of gene x between condition a and b. The conditions themselves should be independent (healthy mice and sick mice in this case).

If I now conduct say 5 experiments determining the expression level of gene x in conditions a and b, I end up with expression values a1,..,a5 and b1,...,b5.

Which of the following analyses is correct?

Case 1: two-sided t-test a[] versus b[]
Case 2: paired t-test (a1,b1);...;(a5,b5). Argument: due to parallel conduction of experiments, similar variation of pipetting errors etc.